# What is the correct way to POST array parameters in ANGULAR?

Tags: angular, post

I am trying to `POST` an array field in my Angular app, and I am having a tough time figuring out the correct way to format the data.

When using a `CURL`, I can successfully `POST` the data with the `--data` attribute:

```
'fields[Name]=Test&fields[Email]=test@test.com&fields[Message]=POST Message!'
```

I tried to set my data parameters up like this:

```
let fields = {
   'fields': {
      'Name': this.contact.name,
      'Email': this.contact.email,
      'Message': this.contact.message
    }
};
```

But this does not appear to be setting up the data correctly to be posted into my API.

What is the correct way I should be setting up the data to match the expected parameters of:

```
fields[Name]
fields[Email]
fields[Message]
```

Thanks for any/all direction.

Comment: If you console.log() the req.body in the backend what format does it have? I would think your data array in a level to deep, you just want let fields = {name, email, message} instead of wrapping it in an extra `fields`.

Comment: I actually noticed that my issue may have been the content-type too. I changed it to `"Accept":"application/json"` and then setup a `new FormData()` and it seems to be working much better.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up the parameters in an object, I set them up into a FormData and everything appears to be working as expected.

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('fields[Name]',this.contact.name);
formData.append('fields[Email]',this.contact.email);
formData.append('fields[Message]',this.contact.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sorry I couldn't catch your issue. If you are Post request and using httpClient 
Then there is a scope that you can directly pass object. It seems your field value is a object So you can directly pass as body in post request

 this.httpClient.post(url, **fields**, htpHeader).subscribe(...

I can see @zeropsi also gave an answer. So you can directly pass such formData also.
```